# GEB get background and text color

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy, geb

I tried the jQuery and javascript approach to get the background or text color but I always got an Exception below.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.css() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [background-color]
```

Heres the code

```js
class BrandingPageSpec extends GebReportingSpec {
    def "Scenario: Selecting a pre-set colours should preview the changes."() {
        expect: "currently at the branding page"
            at BrandingPage

        and: "advance settings hide successfully"
            normalSectionHeader.css("background-color") == "#FFFFFF"

        and: "stays at branding page"
            at BrandingPage
    }
}

class BrandingPage extends Page {

    static at = {
        waitFor(wait: true) {js."document.readyState" == "complete"}
    }

    static content = {
        normalSectionHeader{$('#section-header')}
    }

    static url = "http://someDomain:8080/branding"
}
```

```css
h1{
  background-color: #FFFFFF
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1 id="section-header" > Hello Word </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You want to get `background-color` of `h1`in jquery right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
normalSectionHeader.css("background-color") == "#FFFFFF"
```

For:

```
normalSectionHeader.jquery.css("background-color") == "#FFFFFF"
```

FYI: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/javascript.html#jquery_integration

Comment: Thanks man this one works but it returns rgb(##,##,##) not a hex color value.

Answer (score 0):

[`Navigator.css(String)`](http://www.gebish.org/manual/snapshot/api/geb/navigator/Navigator.html#css(java.lang.String)) method has been added recently and is only available in 0.9.4-SNAPSHOT at the moment.

You'll need to use the snapshot or the workaround suggested by @jripoll.